# Not unique table/alias:

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, alias

Here's a query, i'm getting this error #1066 - **Not unique table/alias: 'tbl_cp_list'**
I have 2 database ie.

```
1) grameenphone_bill ---> 1 table ---> tbl_admin
2) android_appstore ---> 2 Tables ---> tbl_cp_list, tbl_list_data


SELECT `grameenphone_bill`.`tbl_admin`.`cp_id`,`grameenphone_bill`.`tbl_admin`.`cp_name`,`android_appstore`.`tbl_cp_list`.`cpid`,`android_appstore`.`tbl_cp_list`.`cpname`,`android_appstore`.`tbl_list_data`.`cp`,`android_appstore`.`tbl_list_data`.`Count`
FROM
`android_appstore`.`tbl_cp_list`
INNER JOIN `grameenphone_bill`.`tbl_admin`
ON `grameenphone_bill`.`tbl_admin`.`cp_id`=`android_appstore`.`tbl_cp_list`.`cpid`
INNER JOIN `android_appstore`.`tbl_cp_list`
ON `android_appstore`.`tbl_cp_list`.`cpname`=`android_appstore`.`tbl_list_data`.`cp`
```

Please tell , where i'm going wrong? 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had return wrong table name in last JOIN.

Try this:

```
SELECT grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id,grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_name,android_appstore.tbl_cp_list.cpid,
        android_appstore.tbl_cp_list.cpname,android_appstore.tbl_list_data.cp,android_appstore.tbl_list_data.Count 
FROM android_appstore.tbl_cp_list  
INNER JOIN grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin ON grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin.cp_id=android_appstore.tbl_cp_list.cpid 
INNER JOIN android_appstore.tbl_list_data ON android_appstore.tbl_cp_list.cpname=android_appstore.tbl_list_data.cp
```

**You can also use alias names for tables**

```
SELECT b.cp_id, b.cp_name, a.cpid, a.cpname, c.cp, c.Count 
FROM android_appstore.tbl_cp_list a 
INNER JOIN grameenphone_bill.tbl_admin b ON b.cp_id = a.cpid 
INNER JOIN android_appstore.tbl_list_data c ON a.cpname = c.cp
```